# Barplot using ggplot2 for 4 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have data like this:

```
ID  height  S1  S2  S3
1   927 0.90695438  0.28872194  0.67114294
2   777 0.20981677  0.71783084  0.74498220
3   1659    0.35813799  0.92339744  0.44001698
4   174 0.44829914  0.67493949  0.11503942
5   1408    0.90642643  0.18593999  0.67564278
6   1454    0.38943930  0.34806716  0.73155952
7   2438    0.51745975  0.12351953  0.48398490
8   1114    0.12523909  0.10811622  0.17104804
9   1642    0.03014575  0.29795320  0.67584853
10  515 0.77180549  0.83819990  0.26298995
11  1877    0.32741508  0.99277109  0.34148083
12  2647    0.38947869  0.43713441  0.21024554
13  845 0.04105275  0.20256457  0.01631959
14  1198    0.36139663  0.96387150  0.37676288
15  2289    0.57097808  0.66038711  0.56230740
16  2009    0.68488024  0.29811683  0.67998461
17  618 0.97111675  0.11926219  0.74538877
18  1076    0.70195881  0.59975160  0.95007272
19  1082    0.01154550  0.12019055  0.16309071
20  2072    0.53553213  0.78843202  0.32475690
21  1610    0.83657146  0.36959607  0.13271604
22  2134    0.80686674  0.95632284  0.63729744
23  1617    0.08093264  0.91357666  0.33092961
24  2248    0.23890930  0.82333634  0.64907957
25  1263    0.96598986  0.31948216  0.30288836
26  518 0.03767233  0.87770033  0.07123327
27  2312    0.91640643  0.80035100  0.66239047
28  2646    0.72622658  0.61135664  0.75960356
29  1650    0.20077621  0.07242114  0.55336017
30  837 0.84020075  0.42158771  0.53927210
31  1467    0.39666235  0.34446560  0.84959232
32  2786    0.39270226  0.75173569  0.65322596
33  1049    0.47255689  0.21875132  0.95088576
34  2863    0.58365691  0.29213397  0.61722305
35  2087    0.35238717  0.35595337  0.49284063
36  2669    0.02847401  0.63196192  0.97600657
37  545 0.99508793  0.89253107  0.49034522
38  1890    0.95755846  0.74403278  0.65517230
39  2969    0.55165118  0.45722242  0.59880179
40  395 0.10195396  0.03609544  0.94756902
41  995 0.23791515  0.56851452  0.36801151
42  2596    0.86009766  0.43901589  0.87818701
43  2334    0.73826129  0.60048445  0.45487507
44  2483    0.49731226  0.95138276  0.49646702
45  1812    0.57992109  0.26943131  0.46061562
46  1476    0.01618339  0.65883839  0.61790820
47  2342    0.47212988  0.07647121  0.60414349
48  2653    0.04238973  0.07128521  0.78587960
49  627 0.46315442  0.37033152  0.55526847
50  925 0.62999477  0.29710220  0.76897834
51  995 0.67324929  0.55107827  0.40428567
52  600 0.08703467  0.36989059  0.51071981
53  711 0.14358380  0.84568953  0.52353644
54  828 0.90847850  0.62079070  0.99279921
55  1776    0.12253259  0.39914002  0.42964742
56  764 0.72886279  0.29966153  0.99601125
57  375 0.95037718  0.38111984  0.78660025
58  694 0.04335591  0.70113494  0.51591063
59  1795    0.01959930  0.94686529  0.50268797
60  638 0.19907246  0.77282832  0.91163748
61  1394    0.50508626  0.21955016  0.26441590
62  1943    0.92638876  0.71611036  0.17385687
63  2882    0.13840169  0.66421796  0.40033126
64  2031    0.16919458  0.70625020  0.53835738
65  1338    0.60662738  0.27962799  0.24496437
66  1077    0.81587669  0.71225050  0.37585096
67  1370    0.84338121  0.66094211  0.58025355
68  1339    0.78807719  0.04101269  0.20895531
69  739 0.01902087  0.06114149  0.80133001
70  2085    0.69808750  0.27976169  0.63880242
71  1240    0.81509312  0.30196772  0.73633076
72  987 0.56840006  0.95661083  0.43881241
73  1720    0.48006288  0.38981872  0.57981238
74  2901    0.16137012  0.37178879  0.25604401
75  1987    0.08925623  0.84314249  0.46371823
76  1876    0.16268237  0.84723500  0.16861486
77  2571    0.02672845  0.31933115  0.61389453
78  2325    0.70962948  0.13250605  0.95810262
79  2503    0.76101818  0.61710912  0.47819473
80  279 0.85747478  0.79130451  0.75115933
81  1381    0.43726582  0.33804871  0.02058322
82  1800    0.41713645  0.90544760  0.17096903
83  2760    0.58564949  0.19755671  0.63996650
84  2949    0.82496758  0.79408518  0.16497848
85  118 0.79313923  0.75460289  0.35472278
86  1736    0.32615257  0.91139485  0.18642647
87  2201    0.95793194  0.32268770  0.89765616
88  750 0.65301961  0.08616947  0.23778386
89  906 0.45867582  0.91120045  0.98494348
90  2202    0.60602188  0.95517383  0.02133074
```

I want to make a barplot using `ggplot2` like this:
[image]

In the above-mentioned dataset height should be on the y-axis and S1, S2, S3 should be representing colors of each sample.
I have tried the `base R` function `barplot` which gave me the following output. Please give me any suggestion.

`barplot(t(as.matrix(examp[,3:5])),col=rainbow(3))`

[image]

Comment: have a look at "# Stacked barplot with multiple groups" here http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-barplots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization . you likely need to rearrange the S1, S2 and S3 columns into one..

Comment: If height is on the y axis what do the actual numbers associated with each sample tell you? How would you want this represented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what you want to plot. You say you want height on the y axis, but the examples you show are all 'filled to the top', implying the same height for each ID. Also, it is not clear what the numbers associated with each sample represent. I am guessing they should be relative weightings for the bar heights.

Assuming you actually want a filled bar plot as in the examples, with the relative sizes of the bars dictated by the sample values, you can do:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(ID = reorder(ID, S3/(S3 + S2 + S1))) %>%
  pivot_longer(3:5, names_to = "Sample", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(ID, Value * height, fill = Sample)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", color = NA) +
  labs(y = "Height") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

[image]

---

**Alternative**

```r
df %>%
  arrange(order(height)) %>%
  group_by(height) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), mean)) %>%
  pivot_longer(3:5, names_to = "Sample", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(height, Value, fill = Sample, colour = Sample)) +
  geom_smooth(method = loess, formula = y ~ x, linetype = 2, alpha = 0.2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. can you please explain these two lines:
`ggplot(aes(ID, Value * height, fill = Sample)) +`

  `geom_col(position = "fill", color = NA)`
specifically `aes(ID, Value * height, fill = Sample)` , I know here x-axis contain ID but for Y-axis I am little bit confused.

Comment: @Mendel, as in my comment above, I am also confused - about what you want. Here, the y axis always sums to 1, as it must to to have all the bars filling from bottom to top, but showing the relative size of each sample. Can you explain what it is that you actually want on the y axis? Your wuestion says it should be height, but then where are you using the actual sample numbers? Should the bars add up to the value of height?

Comment: actually I want to show the relationship among `height` and these three values of these 90 samples `S1`,`S2`, and `S3`.

Comment: But if height is on the y axis, the height of the bars can't represent their value, unless you want the total height of the three bars to add to `height`, and the size of each red, green, blue segment to represent the relative weightings. There would be other ways to represent the data though, like sample value on the y axis, height on the x axis and using points & lines instead of bars. I could show you either of these if you are interested.

Comment: As for as, the scatter plot is concerned, it looks very weird and seems not meaningful.

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(ID = reorder(ID, S3/(S3 + S2 + S1))) %>%
  pivot_longer(3:5, names_to = "Sample", values_to = "Value")

`ggplot(df1, aes(x= height, y = Value, col = Sample)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(Sample))`

Comment: Can you please suggest to me something very attractive?

Comment: @Mendel the problem is that your data is very noisy with no discernible pattern, so there's no very pretty method I can find, but I'll add something.

Comment: how we can map `height` on this plot? I mean after making a barplot then map `height` on that plot?

Comment: @Mendel I have added the line plot as an example, which shows how each sample changes with height.. As I said, you can't have height on the same axis as the bars representing the sample values - that doesn't make sense. You can have the stacked bars showing the relative sizes of the samples, but even this is a bit misleading. What is it that you are trying to demonstrate with this plot?

Comment: Thanks, this is looking pretty fine. I want to demonstrate the relationship among these S values of each sample with the height, how height affects the Ss.

Comment: @Mendel the line chart is probably the best way of doing that - your data are very noisy, so other options are less pretty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243144/discussion-between-mendel-and-allan-cameron).